# How to ignore Bootgrid click event on certain element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, row, jquery-bootgrid

I have implemented a JQuery bootgrid. My problem is that I want to ignore the row `click` event for when a `select` input in my bootgrid is clicked.

This is what I have so far:

```
.on("click.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e, columns, row, target) {;
    if(/* Clicked element is not a select input */) {
        location.href = "/row?id=" + row.Id;
    }
});
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? I've been struggling around with this for ages now.

**Edit:** Why Alisson's answer doesn't work.

When I do this:

```
.on("click.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e, column, row, target) {
    console.log(row.IncidentId);
});
```

I can get the `IncidentId`, but when I do this:

```
.on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function () {
    grid.find(".some-selector").on("click", function (e) {
        // do what you need here...
        var IncidentId = $(this).closest('tr').data('IncidentId');
        location.href = "/row?id=" + IncidentId;
    });
});
```

It doesn't work because I can't access the `IncidentId` that way.

This is my `<thead>`:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @*<th data-column-id="IncidentId" data-visible="false">Id</th>*@
        <th data-column-id="CaseNumber" data-order="asc">Case Number</th>
        <th data-column-id="Title">Case Title</th>
        <th data-column-id="EntrepreneurContact">Entrepreneur Contact</th>
        <th data-column-id="Mentor">Mentor</th>
        <th data-column-id="StatusReason">Status Reason</th>
        <th data-column-id="CreatedOn">Created On</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
```

I want this:

[image: Working Example]

Not this:

[image: Wrong Example]

Comment: Good, if you add fiddle of this code.

Comment: Barry, I just edited my answer which allows you to use the `click` event in the grid, without having to keep the `IncidendId` column. I also created a working fiddle so you can play around. Let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit: a better solution

You can use the `click` event as you would, but combining with the `loaded` event to stop the propagation of your `select input` events like so:

```
var bootgrid = $("#grid1").bootgrid(config);

bootgrid.on("click.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e, columns, row, target) {
    console.log('Incident Id: ' + row.IncidentId);
});

bootgrid.on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e, c, rows) {
    // avoid any element with "stop-click-event" class from triggering the event in the grid...
    $(".stop-click-event").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

You need to bind to `click` inside the `loaded` event of the grid, because this is where you are sure the elements like your select input **already exist in the DOM**, and since after each reload of the grid (at least for ajax calls) the bootgrid delete all your elements and recreate with new data, `loaded` will be triggered again, so these new elements will be bound again.

[Here is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8g3n53g/4/)

---

### Old solution

Instead of using this `click.rs.jquery.bootgrid` event, bind to `loaded`, and once loaded, bind to the correct elements you need:

```
var grid = $("#my-grid").bootgrid(config)
.on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function () {

    // find elements inside the grid, using some jQuery selector...
    grid.find(".some-selector").on("click", function (e) {
        // do what you need here...
        var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').data('row-id');
        location.href = "/row?id=" + rowId;
    });

});
```

---

If you still need to add a listener to an entire row, for example, and want to avoid a click in a `button` or an `input`, you can do something like this (still inside **loaded** event):

```
// bind to all rows inside the grid...
grid.find("tr").mouseup(function (e) {
    // do something
    var rowId = $(this).data('row-id');
    location.href = "/row?id=" + rowId;
});

// avoid when clicking any "a", "input" or "button" tags...
grid.find("tr td a, tr td input, tr td button").mouseup(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I was originally doing this but then I had no way to get the value of a specific row column value. So this approach didn't work.

Comment: I've edited my question to give an example of what I want to do.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I understand. After generating the rows, your `tr` elements should have a `data-row-id` attribute with their respective `ids`. So you can easily retrieve the `row-id` with my edited code.

Comment: That would be great, if I didn't comment that row out. It's still a problem.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle what do you mean by **commenting that row out**? Your `tr` doesn't have a `data-row-id` attribute? Bootgrid should create it for you, as soon as you define a `<th>` inside your `<thead>` with a `data-identifier` like this: `<th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric" data-visible="false" data-identifier="true">ID</th>`. Take note the `data-visible="false"` is only necessary to make that column hidden.

Comment: You can leave `<th data-column-id="Id"></th>` out and the `row.Id` can still be accessed.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle can't you let that column still there, and just add a `data-visible="false"` to make it hidden?

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I mean, why are you commenting it at all? Usually there is no need to comment an `id` column. If you don't want it visible in the DOM, just add that `data-visible="false"` like I said. It's simpler imo.

Comment: No, because then the user can still choose to show it from their bootgrid display option and I don't want that.

Comment: I've added an edit to my question to help illustrate my problem.

Comment: I've actually just tested your solution and it's not even working.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I've read your edited question. In order for it to work, you need to *uncomment* the `<th data-column-id="IncidentId" data-visible="false">Id</th>`.

Comment: In fact, it doesn't work on any of the columns, even the visible ones.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle oh, I'm sorry. You need to set `data-identifier="true"` attribute in your `<th>` with your `IncidentId` column. I said in one of my previous comments, but forgot to add in my last comment. So: `<th data-column-id="IncidentId" data-identifier="true" data-visible="false">Id</th>`. Adding data-identifier to a column will make **bootgrid** use its value to populate the `data-row-id` attribute in your `<tr>` inside `<tbody>`. So the code should work.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle please, provide a sample fiddle. I use bootgrid in many different apps, and it works. This is the only remaining way I can help you, and I'd like to make it work for you.

Comment: *After Edit:* Thanks, this does exactly what I wanted without any work arounds. Perfect solution!

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I'm sorry for being late, I couldn't figure out before. I'm glad it was what you were looking for :)

Comment: Appreciate the efforts!